# Magento 2.2.2 site loading speed is very slow

Tags: magento2, optimization, speedoptimization

I am using Magento 2.2.2 EE nginx + varnish + cdn still site is loading very slow for the very first time when I flush the cache from terminal using command 'php bin/magento cache:flush' or from backend under cache management.

If you guys have any Idea please share

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please do not execute `php bin/magento cache:flush` in the live site. Clear require cache only.

Comment: I think this is not a solution some time we have to flush cache.

Comment: Then if you flush cache then your site will be loading very slow.

Comment: Cache doesn't speed up Magento, it just masks the slowness. If your site has inefficiencies, they will always show up

Comment: Agree with jiheison... Your best try would be profiling your application with cache disabled, and optimize slower parts of code

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for MySQL server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: i would start from upgrading to 2.3.4 and then check newrelic or profiler

Comment: website having 100+ stores and 70k+ products and all products are configurable having 50+ associate no: of products are 16 on list page.

Form newrelic I am getting slowest component 
https://prnt.sc/r06a1e

Comment: @WilsonHauck https://pastebin.com/6u0dpkK1

Comment: Thank you for the data you have made available, analysis in process - give me 24 hours, please to post some suggestions.  If SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; could be posted to pastebin.com, it likely has some clues available.  If you could post top or htop first page, we would know how much RAM is available.  Is your data storage HDD, SSD or NVME?

Comment: yes data storage is SSD  https://pastebin.com/2d6Pbg9J

Comment: Please post SHOW CREATE TABLE catalog_category_entity; for analysis of the SELECT query displayed in your SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; . Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check following things for improve site speed in Magento:

- Update latest version of Magento 2
- Enable Varnish Cache
- Configure Memcached
- Enable Flat Categories and Products
- Merge & Minify Javascript and CSS
- Setup Content Delivery Network
- Use a good theme
- Optimise Images
- Check 3rd party extension's collection flow
- Check third party URLs : Ex. If fonts load directly from 3rd party URL and then instead of direct URL you can download fonts and put it
  in your Magento and set appropriate path in less or CSS.
- Use SVG images for icons instead of separate images and set SVG using position in CSS.

I hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: already did this @Rohit , Actually We need to improve TTFB after flushing cache

Comment: Magento no longer recommends the use of a flat catalog as a best practice. Continued use of this feature is known to cause performance degradation and other indexing issues. https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/catalog-flat.html

Answer (score 1):

This issue can solved  by running the command

```
php bin/magento cache:enable
```

the common solution for slow load.

Answer (score 0):

**The use of varnish cache really optimized the website speed.** Apart from this you can apply the following methods:

Minify HTML, CSS and JS files

Merge CSS and Javascript

Defer parsing of Javascript

Bundle up JavaScript files

Maximum file size for Javascript Bundle Files

Set up using flat catalog category

Set up using flat catalog product

Displays product images with every scroll

Optimize and compress all product images.

Optimize cached product images on the fly

Loads the entire catalog/product images by just scrolling down

Set the number of preload images on all the pages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to warm up the cache after you clear it on live sites, there are certain extensions available for the same or you can any other DSL like Blackfire player or cURL to crawl all the important pages so it loads from cache for the customers.

**EDIT :**

Found a free extension for the same, seems to use curl to warmup configured pages.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
innodb_io_capacity=1900  # from 200 to use more of your IOPS capacity of your SSD
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 16M to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 82,131
max_connect_errors=100  # from 1,000,000 to frustrate hackers/crackers at 100 attempts to break in
max_connections=500  # from 2500 to conserve RAM footprint since max_used_connections was 251 in 66 days
```

You will find these configuration changes will improve loading speed and reduce CPU BUSY significantly.

These suggestions are just the tip of the iceberg and there are many more Global Variable tuning opportunities.

For additional assistance, please view my profile, Network profile for free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.